Is 名を冠 some kind of expression?
「誰なら犠牲にしていって、俺は思ってたんだろう」
酷いエゴだ。自分は犠牲者のつもりで―いや、実際犠牲は多かった、自分達が犠牲者であることは否定しない。
けれどその名を冠のようにして、他者から奪おうとしている。
The context is... a bit long. But basically the character family is placed under a curse that makes them sacrifices. To get rid of this curse he needs to sacrifice someone else.
I largely understand what he's saying but I'm curious about "その名を冠の"
Is this some kind of expression? My reading is "I made that that name a title and I'm trying to steal it from someone else"?

This is not a set expression.  This might be a partial mis-parsing.
Here's the sample sentence:

けれどその名【な】を冠【かんむり】のようにして、他者【たしゃ】から奪おう【うばおう】としている。

The specific phrase you appear to be grappling with is not 「その名【な】を冠【かんむり】」, but rather 「その名【な】を冠【かんむり】のようにする」.
Breaking it down

その名【な】 -- "that name, that label"
In this case, "that label" refers to the 犠牲者【ぎせいしゃ】 ("victim, sacrifice") mentioned earlier.
を -- object particle
This tells us that the preceding noun, その名【な】, is the object of a verb.  Sometimes that verb is left implied, but in this sentence, we have it explicitly stated.
冠【かんむり】 -- "crown"
Just what it says.  Sometimes used figuratively, as it is here.
のように -- "as, just as, as if, like"
Tells us that whatever comes after is "just as if, just like" the noun or noun phrase that comes before.
する -- "to do", with the specific meaning in translation very dependent on the context.

Whenever you see ～のようにする, it means that the agent (subject or "doer" of the verb) is doing or treating something "just like, just as if" the bit before.
Since we know that the object of this phrase is the その名【な】 bit, we can tell that the agent is treating the その名【な】 ("that label") "just like, just as if" it were a 冠【かんむり】 ("crown").
Putting it back together

けれどその名【な】を冠【かんむり】のようにして、他者【たしゃ】から奪おう【うばおう】としている。
↓
But [he] is treating that label like a crown, and trying to steal it from others / keep it for himself.

HTH!
